# What is the Phase Shift of the Sine Function?

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

In the problem, I know how ot solve for the amplitude, the B, the period and center line. I don't know how to find the phase shift if the question is asking for the sine function. If the function is cosine, the phase shift can be 3.63333. How do I find the phase shift the required function is sine? The boxed ones are the answers.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The sine function has the value $0$ midway between its minimum and maximum.  Here the minimum is low tide and the maximum is high tide.  The zero point will be the time midway between these.

Then when $T$ is that midpoint time, you want $$\sin(\omega T - \phi) = 0$$ so you just need $$\phi = \omega T.$$